# RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Tags: c#, console, rabbitmq

I could not get the RabitMq to work and got this error. I am posting this so others with the same problem can eventually find the solution faster than me - I used several hours to find the solution to the problem.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks @evgenirusev** - https://github.com/devmentors/DNC-DShop/issues/8

**RabitMQ  - Docker** - https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq

[image: img1]

I was trying to get the RabitMq "Hello World" tutorial to work and could not figure out why is it not working.

**This is what worked for me:** - hope it helps someone

**1.  In Docker Terminal "Client"  to make RabitMq Image** - **new Image** -      `docker run -d --hostname my-rabit --name ecomm-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:management`

**2. Than I copied the IP which is** "`192.168.99.100:15672`" with the port `:15672` and used that in the RabitMq as `hostname`  - "Copied from the docker `kitematic` `app`"

**3. In RabitMQ Console App Send And Receive -**         `factory.HostName = "192.168.99.100";`

**4.  In RabitMQ Console App Send And Receive -**       `factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;`

**5. Dont forget - Nuget- "RabbitMQ.Client"**   `<PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="6.2.1" />`

**Receive:**

```
 ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        //factory.UserName = "user";
        //factory.Password = "password";
        //factory.VirtualHost = "/";
        factory.HostName = "192.168.99.100";
        factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();


        //using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

            Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**Send:**

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    //factory.UserName = "user";
    //factory.Password = "password";
    //factory.VirtualHost = "/";
    factory.HostName = "192.168.99.100";
    factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

    //using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        string message = "Hello World!";
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```